# AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait issues

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Looks like orientation for avcapturevideoorientationportrait has been deprecated in iOS 6, since I am trying to fix the Vyne (Vine but it rewrites everything) app right now. Anyone know the new code? Here is my current (deprecated) code:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_captureSession];
[previewLayer setFrame:[_previewContainerView bounds]];
[previewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];
[previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[[_previewContainerView layer] addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

So what would happen if we actually looked in the header instead of lazily making others do it for us?

```
@property(nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoOrientation orientation 
    NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(4_0, 6_0, 
    "Use AVCaptureConnection's videoOrientation instead.");
```

If I were as clever as Sherlock Holmes, I might conclude that we are supposed to use AVCaptureConnection's `videoOrientation` instead.